# Installing Ubuntu Server, the installer won't boot

Tags: installation, server

I downloaded the iso file of Ubuntu Server 12.04 (both 64 and 32 bit) and I burned the image to a blank DVD but the installer is not booting (even when I choose DVD-ROM as the first boot device).  My motherboard is Asus and my OS is Ubuntu Desktop. Also there is no autorun and start.exe inside the image that I downloaded.

These are the files inside the .iso I downloaded:

[image: iso file contents]

Comment: Do [md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) check of the ISO image .Also `autorun and start.exe` are not needed for Ubuntu ISO images. Also **[BOOT]** seems to be missing in file folder.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints :

- Reburn your DVD
- Check your DVD once burned with md5
- Try your DVD on another workstation

But afaik, you dvd listing files looks not complete

You said you downloaded both version, I guess you will have to choose one.

Comment: i downloaded both version so i can see if it will work, but same happens, the installer wont start, even when my 1st boot device was my dvd drive. Have you tried installing Ubuntu Server? can u tell me how?

Comment: NOTE : Im installing "Ubuntu Server" not "Ubuntu Desktop"